# Responsive - Hiding facebook page plugin on certain width

Tags: html, css, facebook, responsive-design, responsive

I was trying to hide facebook page plugin but it looks like it doesn't work. Here's my code on CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
.fb-page{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

here's the HTML part where I store FB.

```
<section id="login-form" class="no-margin customloginform">
    <label>Username: </label><br /><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername" type="text" CssClass="centermargin" class="form-control" required="required"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <label>Password: </label><br /><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" type="password" CssClass="centermargin" class="form-control" required="required"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" type="submit" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" name="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg centermargin" required="required" Text="Login" Width="150px"></asp:Button>
    <center><a href="Account/ForgotPassword.aspx">Forgot Password</a></center>
    <center style="color:#ffffff">Not a member? <a href="Account/Register.aspx">Register</a></center><br /><br />
    <div class="hidden-sm"><div class="fb-page " data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TechKidPHMods/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="280" data-height="409" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/TechKidPHMods/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TechKidPHMods/">TechKidPHMods</a></blockquote></div></div>
</section>
```

So any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Show us your HTML. You should use `display: none` instead, but neither one's going to work if the FB page plugin isn't in an element with `class="fb-page"` on it.

Comment: I've updated it. Check :)

Comment: Try putting the class on the `<div class="hidden-sm">` bit instead. The Facebook page code will replace your `<div class="fb-page">` with the actual plugin HTML and I'll bet it wipes out the class when it does so.

Comment: `class="fb-page"`    was required by fb for that div part so yeah... even adding a new div with    `class="hidden-sm"`    doesn't work

Comment: Frankly, I think we're going to need to see a real example page of the issue. Something else is going on. Are you using Bootstrap in your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the reason your `display: none`s aren't working is you have other rules in play.

[image]

You have a few choices:

- Put an `!important` on your CSS `.fb-page { display: none }` media query.
- Apply your media query later on in your list of CSS rules (after the two rules in the screenshot)
- Put an ID on the div you want to hide instead of a class.

Consider learning your browser's web developer tools. This sort of problem can be easily debugged with them, as they'll show exactly why a particular rule is being ignored.

Comment: okay I did try to use to use `.fb-page { display: none !important; }` but that didn't work

But now I do have an idea and tried this 

`#fbwidget, #facebook, .plugin{
        display: none !important;
    }`

And oh boy it works. Literally added fbwidget id on fb's div then yes I do checked everything on chrome's inspect element. Added #facebook and .plugin and it works

Comment: Thank you for pointing that :D .I do use dev tools but looks like I didn't notice those. Hehe. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
.fb-page{
    display: none;
}
```

or if you are using Bootstrap try hidden-xs or hidden-sm.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're missing the closing brace for `.fb-page` but I'd also say you should use `display: none` if you want to completely hide something at that breakpoint. Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
  .fb-page {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: just copied the line of code from VS so yeah it misses something but its not... 

Anyways, display: none; didn't do the trick :(

Comment: Do you have a URL of the page you're working on? It would be helpful to see the full markup and cascade going on.

Comment: Currently, it's on localhost but go check the question again, I've updated it